# How to plot the difference between multiple variables that start with the same prefix using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a R (tibble) data frame with multiple variables starting with the same name but ending with numbers that form a sequence (e.g., var2000, var2001,..., var2020). Conceptually, I would like to perform the loop in the code below:

```
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

df <- tibble(key     = seq(1, 100), 
             var2000 = round(runif(100)), 
             var2001 = round(runif(100)))
plots <- vector('list', length = 0)
for (t in seq(2001, 2001)) {
  plots[[as.character(t)]] <- ggplot(data = df) + 
    geom_bar(aes_string(x = paste0('var', t) - paste0('var', t - 1)))
}
```

However, it throws an error when I try to run it. Is there a way to perform this loop without having to create a new variable for the difference `var_{t} - var_{t - 1}`?

Comment: What is the specific output you want?

Comment: I want to collect the bar plots in the plot list (_plots_ in the code) that I created, where each item of the list is the bar plot of the difference between consecutive pairs (e.g., var2001 - var2000). I know that the problem in my code is with the ```paste0('var', t) - paste('var', t - 1)``` part, but I don't know how to write it differently so it could work.

Comment: Can you give an example of code that produces a single one of the plots you want? I'm not clear how you expect `geom_bar` to work with only an x value. Do you want something like `ggplot(df, aes(key, var2001-var2000)) + geom_col()`?

Comment: An example that worked for me is the following:
```
df <- tibble(key     = seq(1, 100), 
             var2000 = round(runif(100)), 
             var2001 = round(runif(100)))
ggplot(data = df) + geom_bar(aes(x = var2001 - var2000))
```
However, I need to generate plots for every difference of var(t + 1) - var(t) in my data set, but ```aes_string``` does not seem accept ```paste0('var', t) - paste0('var', t - 1)``` as an argument. (Sorry, I meant to write ```paste0``` instead of ```paste``` in the example that I initially gave.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your particular error can be avoided by creating difference columns as below
(But unpivoting the data, as the answer by Jon Spring, is more general and usually preferred approach).

```r
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

df <- tibble(key     = seq(1, 100), 
             var2000 = round(runif(100)), 
             var2001 = round(runif(100)))
plots <- vector('list', length = 0)
for (t in seq(2001, 2001)) {
  df[[paste0("diff", t)]] <- df[[paste0('var', t)]] - df[[paste0('var', t - 1)]]
  plots[[as.character(t)]] <- ggplot(data = df) + 
    geom_bar(aes_string(x = paste0("diff", t)))
}
```

Comment: 説明どうもうありがとう。I am knew to R and I thought that it was possible to write an expression for the _x_ argument in ```aes_string``` (without having to create a new variable in my data frame). I'll use this method in my code. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I would normally do something like this, using dplyr to calculate the lags in long formatted data, and then putting those into facets:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(42)
df <- tibble(key     = seq(1, 100), 
             var2000 = round(runif(100)), 
             var2001 = round(runif(100)),
             var2002 = round(runif(100)))

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-key) %>%
  
  group_by(key) %>% 
  mutate(dif = value - lag(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(!is.na(dif)) %>%
  
  group_by(name) %>%
  count(dif) %>%
  ungroup() -> df2
  
  ggplot(df2, aes(dif, n)) +
  geom_col() + 
  facet_wrap(~name)
```

[image]

If you want to put those facets into a list, you could use:

```
plots <- vector('list', length = 0)
for(t in df2$name) {
  plots[[as.character(t)]] <- ggplot(data = df2 %>% filter(name == t)) + 
    geom_col(aes(dif, n))
}

plots[1]
```

[image]

```
plots[2]
```

[image]